# How to detect these white spots?

Tags: c#, opencv

I have an image where I need to count the white spots. I tried this code, but it works badly:

```
CircleSegment[] circles;
Mat dst = new Mat();
Mat train = new Mat(path, ImreadModes.Grayscale);

Cv2.GaussianBlur(train, dst, new OpenCvSharp.Size(1, 1), 4, 550);
circles = Cv2.HoughCircles(dst, HoughMethods.Gradient, 5, 50, 1, 60, 1, 60);

for (int i = 0; i < circles.Length; i++)
{
    count++;
    Cv2.Circle(dst, (OpenCvSharp.Point)circles[i].Center, (int)circles[i].Radius, new Scalar(125), 2);
}

using (new Window("Circles", dst))
{
    Cv2.WaitKey();
}
MessageBox.Show(count.ToString(), "Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

I attach the original image, and the result:

[image: Original image]

[image: Result]

Comment: I think the problem is that your circles are not perfect circles, you may have to use another tool for it

Comment: try using the countour detector

Answer (score 1):

After binarization, you can simply feed your image to [`Cv2.ConnectedComponents`](https://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp_docs/html/7dbbc5e1-4484-35bb-bedc-fc47c017e1a1.htm). For more information, see the corresponding OpenCV function [`cv::connectedComponents`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaedef8c7340499ca391d459122e51bef5).

That'd be the minimal code to get the number of the white spots:

```cs
using OpenCvSharp;

namespace OpenCVSharpTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var img = new Mat("z4BL7.png", ImreadModes.Grayscale);
            Cv2.Threshold(img, img, 0, 255, ThresholdTypes.Otsu);

            using var labels = new Mat();
            int ncc = Cv2.ConnectedComponents(img, labels);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Number of white spots: " + ncc.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The console output is:

```
Number of white spots: 551
```

Since I'm more fluent in (the) Python (API of OpenCV), especially for visualization purposes, here's the corresponding code for that, too:

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('z4BL7.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

ncc, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(img)
print('Number of white spots:', ncc)

# Just for visualization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(labels)
plt.show()
```

Console output is the same, and here's the visualization:

[image: Visualization]

```
-----------------------------------------------------
System information
-----------------------------------------------------
Platform:                   Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0

Visual Studio Prof. 2019:   16.4.4
OpenCvSharp4.Windows:       4.5.2.20210404

Python:                     3.9.1
PyCharm:                    2021.1.1
Matplotlib:                 3.4.1
OpenCV:                     4.5.1
-----------------------------------------------------
```